# Find function, underlying date value

Tags: vba, excel

So I have been stuck with an issue regarding finding lastmonth in my sheet.´The months in my sheet are made up of EOMONTH Formulas. Therefore I would like to find the underlying value for each month´so I can disregard formating issues.

```
Function Last_Day_Of_the_Month()

Dim WrkMonths As Integer
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Long

StartDate = Now
EndDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(StartDate, -1)


Cells.Find(What:=EndDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


End Function
```

This just returns the error 91 that it cannot find the value.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Abit embarassing as I can swear this code didnt work before... But I solved my issue, here is the code I used if anyone else needs it.

```
Sub lastdayofthemonth()


      Dim StartDate As Date
      Dim EndDate As Date

    StartDate = Now
    EndDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(StartDate, -1)


    Cells.Find(What:=Format(EndDate, "MMMM YYYY"), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `EndDate` variable as a `Date` rather than a `Long` it should work providing the value is on the active sheet.
If it's not you'll still get the error 91. To avoid this set a variable to store the found date and check if it contains anything before activating.

```
Sub Last_Day_Of_the_Month()

    Dim WrkMonths As Integer
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim rFound As Range

    StartDate = Now
    EndDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(StartDate, -1)

    Set rFound = Cells.Find(What:=EndDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        rFound.Activate
    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is if I store it as date it looks for the value 2016-03-31. This value does exist in my sheet but with another "Swedish" formating option. Therefore I would like to search for the value 42460 (which stands for 2016-03-31) instead and i therefore dim as long.

Comment: Had a read of http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-dates.htm.  Try changing `EndDate` to a string data type, update `EndDate=Worksheet...` to `EndDate = Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(StartDate, -1), "Short Date")` - change "Short Date" to the correct format.  Then in the FIND statement change `EndDate` to `CDATE(EndDate)`.